# Apply material texture to a 3D model in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 3D model(part of heart) and also I have created a texture to apply on to it.
Unfortunately if I apply to the 3D model it doesnt look good. But I did the same for a cube and its nicely work as I expected. The below is the figure. [image]

You can see the cube is more realistic, however, if I apply to my model, it is not very good. Any suggestion why this is happening?

Comment: Besides the texture you need UV mapping of your heart model (which makes a correspondence of where on texture each vertex is located)

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! If you're not specifically using that language don't use that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cube is "unwrapped" - it has a UV Map. Your Heart-Mesh does not.

You need to UV-Map / Unwrap your Heart-Mesh.

In **Blender**:
For this, you could try "Smart UV Project" in EditMode, but that will create small islands and you get a lot of seams.
[image]

By hand, you could mark seams and choose "unwrap" which can result in a
better UV map.

**Alternative**: Use a Triplanar Shader. Probably a good idea for a repeating texture like yours. [image]

(I got that image from this reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/ndh9ll/simple_triplanar_shader_in_unity/)